Get properties in tasklet
Is it possible to get variables from a properties file (ex: application.properties) in a tasklet ?
This is my example :
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTasklet.class);

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
String db_username;

 @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

log.info("db_username : " + db_username);
…
}

My log return null for db_username.
Regards.

An @Value cannot be null, if it cannot be resolved Spring will throw an exception. Hence the conclusion is that your tasklet is not managed by Spring (the instance you are actually using is probably created using new). I would also remove the @PropertySource as I suspect you are using Spring Boot.

That should not be the case. Are you using spring Boot? Is that tasklet placed in a package scanned by Spring Boot?

My instance was created using new. Problem solved. Thank you very much to you 2.
